# How to sort alphabetical order in two arrayList

Tags: android, sorting

How to sort the alphabetical order in android.

```
Button sort=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sort)
sort.setonClickListener()
Public void onclick(view v)
{

Collections.sort(str3, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

                        customlist      = new CustomResourseList(Resourse1.this, str3,str4);
                      resourseList.setAdapter(customlist);
}
```

but I use this way means I got the result for,

before sort:

```
mani
180 cross street

Level wedding planner
alphama

ziaasdf
234fasd
```

After sort:

```
Level wedding planner
180 cross street

mani
alphama

ziaasdf
234fasd
```

But I want the result for below way

```
Level wedding planner
alphama

mani
180 cross street

ziaasdf
234fasd
```

How to sort the coding?

Answer (score 2):

try to custom Comparator

```
 Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() 
 {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) 
    {
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
});
```

Comment: do you know? you are doing the same comparison as String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER does... then why to use Custom Comparator?

Comment: @GopalRao in case he ever has to change the comparison operator.

Comment: @GopalRao doing it this way is more generic and allows him to sort using any criteria in the future, if it's needed.  It's minimal effort to add this, as opposed to arguing that you aren't going to need it, so he just went ahead and did it.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringArraySort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] MyStringArray = { "mani 180 cross street",
                "Level wedding planner alphama", "ziaasdf 234fasd" };
        Arrays.sort(MyStringArray, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(MyStringArray));
    }
}

output:[Level wedding planner alphama, mani 180 cross street, ziaasdf 234fasd]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to below solution

```
package com.caloriapp.nutrition;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.caloriapp.R;

/**
 * @author ACCESS
 * 
 */
public class SortActivity extends Activity {
    // String[] _StrOne = new String[] { "mani", "Level wedding planner",
    // "ziaasdf" };
    // String[] _StrTwo = new String[] { "180 cross street", "alphama",
    // "234fasd" };
    Map<String, String> olympic2012 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> sorted = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ListView listView1;
    LayoutInflater LI;
    Iterator i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sort);
        LI = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Arrays.sort(_StrOne);
        //
        // for (String c : _StrOne) {
        // System.out.println(c);
        // }

        olympic2012.put("mani", "180 cross street");
        olympic2012.put("level wedding planner", "alphama");
        olympic2012.put("ziaasdf", "234fasd");
        olympic2012.put("russia", "234fasd");
        // olympic2012.put("Australia", 4); //adding duplicate value

        // printing hashtable without sorting
        System.out.println("Unsorted Map in Java : " + olympic2012);

        // sorting Map e.g. HashMap, Hashtable by keys in Java
        sorted = sortByKeys(olympic2012);
        System.out.println("Sorted Map in Java by key: " + sorted);
        Set set = sorted.entrySet();
        // Get an iterator
        i = set.iterator();
        listView1.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());

    }

    public static <K extends Comparable, V extends Comparable> Map<K, V> sortByKeys(
            Map<K, V> map) {
        List<K> keys = new LinkedList<K>(map.keySet());
        Collections.sort(keys);

        // LinkedHashMap will keep the keys in the order they are inserted
        // which is currently sorted on natural ordering
        Map<K, V> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
        for (K key : keys) {
            sortedMap.put(key, map.get(key));
        }

        return sortedMap;
    }

    /*
     * Java method to sort Map in Java by value e.g. HashMap or Hashtable throw
     * NullPointerException if Map contains null values It also sort values even
     * if they are duplicates
     */
    public static <K extends Comparable, V extends Comparable> Map<K, V> sortByValues(
            Map<K, V> map) {
        List<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>(
                map.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<K, V> o1, Entry<K, V> o2) {
                return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
            }
        });

        // LinkedHashMap will keep the keys in the order they are inserted
        // which is currently sorted on natural ordering
        Map<K, V> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();

        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entries) {
            sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        return sortedMap;
    }

    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public CustomAdapter() {

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return sorted.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.widget.BaseAdapter#getViewTypeCount()
         */
        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return sorted.size();
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.widget.BaseAdapter#getItemViewType(int)
         */
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LI.inflate(R.layout.sort_raw, null);

                TextView txtname = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                if (i.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
                    System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
                    System.out.println(me.getValue());
                    txtname.setText(me.getKey() + "  " + me.getValue());
                }
                //

            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```